# Conditional slicing in python

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-slicing

How can I select specific rows, where these rows equal to another row in another parallel array?
in other words; can I vectorize code? here p, y are ndarray withe the same shape

```
for inx,val in enumerate(p):
    if val ==y[inx]:
        pprob.append(1)
    else:
        pprob.append(0)
```

Comment: Please post a complete MCVE

Answer (score 1):

```
import numpy as np

a = np.random.normal(size=(10, 5))
b = np.random.normal(size=(10, 5))

a[1] = b[1]
a[7] = b[7]

rows = np.all(a == b, axis=1).astype(np.int32)
rows = rows.tolist()   # if you really want the result to be a list
print(rows)
```

Result as expected

```
[0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0]
```

If you could be dealing with more than two dimensions, change the following (works for 2d as well):

```
# this
np.all(a == b, axis=1)
# to this
np.all(a == b, axis=tuple(range(len(a.shape)))[1:])
```

Answer (score 1):

I just ran this in a python shell in Python 3.9.4

```
import numpy as np

x = np.array([1,2,3,4,5])
y = np.array([1,1,3,3,5])

matching_idx = np.where(x == y) # (array([0, 2, 4]),)

x[matching_idx] # array([1, 3, 5])
```

Seems like `x[matching_idx]` is what you want

The key to this is `np.where()`, explained [here](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html)